# Running GitHub Actions unders specific, existing Windows user

Tags: powershell, certificate, active-directory, github

I am trying to run a GHA workflow in a GitHub-hosted runner for Windows (`windows-latest`) under a specific, already existing Windows user instead of the default `C:\Users\runneradmin`.

Options involving [net user or runas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70904273/can-i-specify-a-user-account-for-a-github-action-step-on-a-windows-runner) apparently attempt to create a new, local user in the runner. I need to add to the runner an already existing AD user, but I'm a little lost going looking at the [ActiveDirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70904273/can-i-specify-a-user-account-for-a-github-action-step-on-a-windows-runner) module.

For context, I need to run the workflow as a particular user (from a particular domain) because the flow uses digital certificates (and a cert manager called RedTrust) that are assigned to this particular user. Up until now I have been running my GHA workflow under a self-hosted Windows machine (AWS EC2 instance) where the user already exists, but I am now tasked with doing the same in a GitHub-hosted runner.

I've tried asking the IT department but they seem confused as to what I'm asking so before I ask them again, or keep trying various Powershell commands, I'm hoping to get a broader idea of whether what I'm asking makes sense at all.

Comment: Ask your IT department "How can a system that is not part of AD get the certificate that the workflow needs?"

Answer (score 1):

> under a specific, already existing Windows user

It is not an "already existing user", because the VM is not part of the Active Directory domain in which the user exists. There is no procedure nor a PowerShell command to pull individual AD accounts into a non-AD machine. (In earlier Windows versions, `ksetup /mapuser` could achieve something along those lines, but it's nowhere near being a standard procedure… and when it comes to full logins, it needs something equivalent to a full domain join anyway.)

To bring the user into existence, the VM needs to be "joined" to the domain (provisioned with an AD computer account) – and of course given access to access the domain's DCs through any firewalls – at which point all AD users will automatically become available. Try asking your IT "How do I join throwaway VMs to AD?" and "Can a VM that's outside the company network access AD?"

Only after that, you would become able to `runas` to any user in that domain without having to explicitly create it, as Windows would automatically look up AD domain accounts. (Though the remaining question is whether RedTrust would still kick in for 'runas'; it seems like the kind of software that requires a full login – and that's *not* going to be performed by GitHub's automation.)

Non-domain-joined machines can still use `runas /netonly` or `cmdkey /add` to let a local account use an AD account's Kerberos credentials for *network* operations (which is really all you need anyway; the local process identity doesn't seem to be relevant), but that's likewise even less likely to be compatible with your certificate system.

So in general I don't think it will be *useful* to attempt this. (Not just because of the technical reasons, but also because I have a feeling you're trying to make the CI runner use *your own* AD account… which would be a problem.) Instead, if your process needs a certificate in order to access some system, focus on the actual need for access – not on a particular mechanism of achieving it.

Ask your IT department "How can I get certificates for XX and YY from a non-AD system?" or "How can I get certificates for a service / a batch job / a scheduled task?" and they might give you other options than having to go through the regular-user-oriented system.

Comment: @JSalazAlt - We really can't assist you since it requires your IT Administrator to everything we might suggest.